# Control flow of logs from logstash forwarder

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

I want to control flow of logs from logstash forwarder client, as for now it reads the entire log file from beginning, which is not required in the project. 
[image]

I want that the logs before Nov 10, 2015 should not be forwarded to the logstash Server. Is there a way we can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply drop the events that are too old in your logstash indexer config by using the drop filter:

```
  if [somevalue] < X {
     drop { }
  }
```

Check the docs at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html